# Fast Loading/Storing of large tree/graph-ish data structures using conventional database (long)

Tags: c#, mysql

**Requirements:**

- Let's have conventional **mysql** database server.
- Let's have **C# .net** app using mysql connector.
- Let's have set of tables (designed to fit the complex tree/graph like data structures and their relations).
- The data structures can be fairy large and can contain many (hundreds to thousands) blob items (10 to 100kiB per item).
- Allow loading/storing of data structures from/to database as fast as possible.
- Let's have three freely convertible representations of any data structure (sub)item: xml, C# object in memory, sql.

**Current solution:**

- It emerged via some sort of evolution, this means no big knowledge of applicable/typical methods was present (also - as usual - the original requirements were not so demanding).
- Each data structure (sub)item implements (custom) `ISqlSerializable` interface having (among others) `ReadSql(...)` and `WriteSql(...)` methods. (Inspired by `IXmlSerializable`, which also has to be implemented due to XML serialization requirements).
- Custom (De)Serializer calls such methods for each (root) data structure.
- These calls emit SQL commands for reading/writing the data structure itself followed by the serialization requests for children (if any) - the same approach used by the `IXmlSerializable`.
- This sequence emits the SQL code for the whole tree/graph disregarding the fact what is the root (you can fully de/serialize any data structure via calling `ISqlSerializable` - I mean, the root might be almost any structure implementing `ISqlSerializable`).

**Problems:**

- This approach is terribly slow, beacuse e.g. reading/writing N adjacent objects from/to single table means N select/insert commands instead of possibly single effective one.
- Sort of caching has been introduced (for loading, up to now) to speedup the process:

  - The preseleted root structure prefetches all the tables/rows/columns via `DataAdapters`/`DataSets` and complex sql commands.
  - All the (sub)structures then read itself from such built cache and do not emit SQL code to server.
  - It dramatically improved the speed, but it's still lot of hardwired SQL emiting code for few preselected root structures.
  - The responsibility to load/store children's data is now up to the parent who needs to know the wider context ("what exactly is the full rest of me") than in previous case: "handle myself, then let the children to handle themselves".

**Questions:**

- What is the typical method to solve such task? I mean, what would use people who do this kind of tasks "every day"? I do not suspect this is somehow special scenario...
- Nice candidate seems to be stored procedures approach:

  - SQL/app code isolation.
  - Possibility to update/tune the SQL code with no/little impact to app code.
  - Probaly better efficiency when everything SQL related runs on server side.
  - Is that the best way (before we rebuild the whole app)?
  - Is there a standard way to create sql-stored-procedure-driven conversion accepting/generating multi-table DataSets writing/reading multiple tables to/from mysql database (something more practical than simple 'hello-world' example which will perform superfast even on 386)?

***Please note:*** I'm not expecting fully working copy/paste source code in first answer, just general ideas/thoughts/kicks from developers more experienced in this particular area, considering current state and possible future improvement. I hope I'll manage the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Why store it in a RDBMS if the structure suits another type of data store? You say **Let's have conventional mysql database server**, but not _why_.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a requirement... For example: backward compatibility, extremely inflexible customer.

Comment: @ Adam Houldsworth I suppose you would recommend OODBMS or ORDBMS, in the case we have full flexibility, is there anything you would recommend namely for C#?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, I'd have to review the requirements and schema.